# Show pid on the terminal title bar

Tags: gnome-terminal, gui, titlebar

Is it possible to show the pid of the terminal on its title bar?

Sometimes I have to kill a terminal window without having GUI control and I have to know its pid.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the original issue? Why do you ever have to kill a terminal, and why don't you have GUI controls?

Answer (score 2):

If all you truly want to see is the pid then in the terminal type:

```
PS1="${PS1/\\u@\\h: \\w/$$}"
```

If you want this to be persistent every time you open your terminal then add the command somewhere near the bottom of `~/.bashrc` after all the other `PS1` definitions are set.

Comment: The question was the pid of the terminal, not the pid of the shell.

Comment: Thank you I missed the nuance of that. I'll refine the answer after work.

Comment: Probably we'll need OP to refine the question, for us to better understand the actual problem :)

Comment: Thanks! This works well until I do ssh in the terminal. After ssh the title of the terminal changes and typing this command again would give me another number that's not the original one. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Hi271 Save the number before doing SSH and display the saved number instead of the new SSH number. How exactly to set it up I'll need to contemplate on....

Comment: @egmont FYI there have been new developments on this thread.